# ssr functional for the dft=userd in MRCC package

Tags: density-functional-theory, mrcc

I found the nice `userd` example with the standard functional in the latest MRCC manual but I wonder if one can also use `ssr` (local-scaling approximation) for the `userd` functional.

For example, as shown in example 18 on page 74, doing **XYG9[f2]@B44LYP** but substituting the LDA correlation part into **ssrLDA_C_VWN** with `omega=0.5` at the second `userd` block.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I got a message from a developer and they said it can be done by adding a long-range Hartree-Fock exchange with a small global parameter like this >> 0.000000001 lrHFx 0.5 
where 0.5 stands for the omega value. They said this lrHFx should be put in both first and second userd block. And then, at the second block, one can use the ssr functional like 0.21 ssrLDA_C_VWN where 0.21 is just an arbitrary global parameter and that ssr functional will use the 0.5 as a range-separated parameter.

Comment: Did you get this working in the end?

Comment: I've emailed nesquik91 to write a self-answer if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example input file (MINP) for calculating $E_{XC}=1.0E^{HF}_X+1.0E^{srLYP}_C$ where the range separated omega value equals to 0.33.

```
basis = 6-31g
symm  = off
dft   = userd
2
1.0 HFx
0.000000001 lrHFx 0.33
2
1.0 ssrGGA_C_LYP
0.000000001 lrHFx 0.33


mult     = 1
mem      = 5000MB

unit=angs
geom=xyz
3

O   0.0000   0.0000   0.0626
H  -0.7920   0.0000  -0.4973
H   0.7920   0.0000  -0.4973
```